# MvvmCross Xamarin error cannot find view for ViewModel in IOS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I updated Mvvmcross from 5.7 to 6.x. Navigation is working but its not working when I introduce BaseViewModel. 
This is the sample of my StartPageViewModel

```
public class StartPageViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
protected readonly IUserSettings _userSettings;
private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;

public StartPageViewModel(IUserSettings userSettings,
IMvxNavigationService navigationService)
{
_userSettings = userSettings;
_navigationService = navigationService;
}
public IUserSettings UserSettings
{
get
{
return _userSettings;
}
}
 ]private IMvxCommand _loginCommand;
    public IMvxCommand LoginCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _loginCommand ?? (_loginCommand = new MvxCommand(() => 
         _navigationService.Navigate<LoginViewModel>()));
        }
    }

    public void NavigateToDashboardIfAlreadyLoggedIn()
    {

    }

    public override void Start()
    {
        base.Start();
        NavigateToDashboardIfAlreadyLoggedIn();
    }
}
```

A sample of LoginViewModel

```
public class LoginViewModel : BaseValidationViewModel
{


    public LoginViewModel(IMvxLogProvider logProvider,
        IUserSettings userSettings,
        IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
        IEventLogger eventLogger,
        IMvxNavigationService navigationService)
     : base(userSettings, eventLogger, authenticationManager, navigationService)
    {

        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }
}
```

I want to navigate to LoginViewModel using BaseViewModel but my viewmodel cannot see the view i.e LoginView.

a sample of BaseValidationViewModel

```
public abstract class BaseValidationViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    protected BaseValidationViewModel(IUserSettings userSettings,
    IEventLogger eventLogger,
    IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
    IMvxNavigationService navigationService)
    : base(userSettings, eventLogger, authenticationManager, navigationService)
{
   //Some Code
}
 //Some Code
public override void Start() 
{
 base.Start();
}
}
```

BaseViewModel

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    protected readonly IUserSettings _userSettings;
    protected readonly IEventLogger _eventLogger;
    protected readonly IAuthenticationManager _authenticationManager;
    private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;


    protected BaseViewModel(IUserSettings userSettings,
        IEventLogger eventLogger,
        IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
        IMvxNavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _userSettings = userSettings;
        _eventLogger = eventLogger;
        _authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }


    public override void Start()
    {
        base.Start();

    }

}
```

a sample of LoginView

```
`[Register("LoginView")]
[MvxViewFor(typeof(LoginViewModel))]   
public partial class LoginView : MvxViewController<LoginViewModel>     
{
}`
```

Comment: So it does not crash but just shows a blank screen when you navigate to LoginViewModel? Are you using Storyboards? `MvxViewFor` doesn't do anything unless you are on WPF, which you are not.

Comment: Hi @Cheesebaron, I am not using using Storyboards but the app does not crush or show blank screen. but it remains in StartPageView.. I also put break point in LoginViewModel,  It shows that it navigate but it can't show LoginView

Comment: Hi @Cheesebaron, I also tried to use [MvxChildPresentation] in my LoginView but still the is not showing the LoginView page:
[MvxChildPresentation]
     public partial class LoginView : MvxViewController<LoginViewModel>     
      {
     }

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by mapping view to viewmodel like this in the InitializeViewLookup

```
protected override IMvxViewsContainer InitializeViewLookup(IDictionary<Type, Type> viewModelViewLookup)
{
    viewModelViewLookup.Add(typeof(UserDatabaseUpgradeViewModel),typeof(UserDatabaseUpgradeView));
}
```

Hope this will solve also your problem. I'm using MvvmCross 6.4.x